# Unable to renew Certificate on Windows 10 in domain

Tags: windows, active-directory, certificate, ad-certificate-services

I'm trying to renew my computer certificates on a in domain laptop but I get "RPC Server is unavailable", error code 1722.
On other laptops the same procedure works.
What can I do?
I've opened mmc and then "Personal-All Tasks->Request new certificate".

Comment: I'm going to guess time or DNS issue. Ping your domain.local and if that works, check logs on both, the computer and the domain server/CA

Comment: I was guessing the same, but I can ping and nslookup the domain

Comment: From the client, use CertUtil to ping the request interface of all your CA servers to make sure they're all up: CertUtil -ping -config <ca server name>

Comment: The CA servers are working, from other laptops I can renew or request other certs.